# Meteor, Which mongo query is more performant?

Tags: mongodb, meteor

I'm part way through building a social app where users have an activity feed. The items in the feed will be the same for users if they belong to the same group.

So... the app has many groups which users can optionally belong to. If an event occurs a activity feed item will get created for each user in that group.

But i'm now coming round to the idea of having a single document which has an array of userIds, There are no actions which can be taken against a activity feed item so we dont have nothing to worry about there.

My question really is which one of the two methods would be the best or is there a better alternative? It's expected that a group could hold over 10k users.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Check my understanding:

- 1 user has many groups, 1 group has many users (M:N).
- 1 user has 1 activity feed (1:1)
- 1 activity feed has many events (1:M)
- 1 event has many users (1:M)

So, your collections are:

- Users
- Groups
- Events

Each event would have a FK of `groupId`. Each user would have an array of `groupId`s.

Your query to create a user activity feed would be:

```
Events.find({groupId: {$in: user.groups}});
```

Index on groupId, and when it comes time to scale, you can save a default activity feed & send that to everyone who doesn't have groups (or has the default groups). IIRC this is what reddit does.

Try to stay away from using arrays in 1:M relationships.

Comment: Thanks that makes perfect sense.

Answer (score 0):

One option that you didn't mention is to create something like a `Memberships` collection where documents have the form `{userId, groupId}` and to create a unique compound index on the two fields, as in

```
Memberships._ensureIndex({groupId: 1, userId: 1}, {sparse: true, unique: true})
```

It would probably make sense to create the index this way as you will be looking for the users in a particular group, and joining the posts to that group id. If you're going to look up groups by user, then you can index `userId` first.

If you're going to show the activity from the union of multiple groups at the same time for each user, you might run into the [reactive join](https://www.discovermeteor.com/blog/reactive-joins-in-meteor/) issue, in which case it may be simpler to not update the feed if the group changes until the user refreshes the page.

Comment: Ill expand a bit more..Im only ever interested in getting activity feed items for "current user". Its only ever going to be a flat list similar to Facebook

Answer (score 0):

I would suggest that you create your own `publish` method so that you only subscribe to relevant data an do not deploy too much data to the local mongo. You may find an example with Flow-Router and route based subscriptions here:

http://meteorpad.com/pad/Ba5DTe94NjFi3ZTPA/Playground_Flow-Router_Chat

Answer (score 0):

I would say the most performant option would be for each activity feed to be embedded in each User document:

```
{
  "firstname" : "Joe",
  "lastname" : "Bloggs",
  "activities": [{
    "title": "Someone did something"
  }, {
    "title": "Someone did something else"
  }]
}
```

Taking Facebook as an example, I imagine the items on an activity feed rarely change. But they will get read an awful lot.  Doing an expensive join query (on a non-relational NoSQL offering) everytime you load an activity feed will slow down performance.

You'll be better off embedding it in the `User` itself as when you have the current user in your hand, you'll also have their activity feed in your hand.

When an activity gets raised & that needs to get added to 10K users, then that will certainly take longer. But that can happen in the background & take as long as required. It's not vital that a user sees a friends activities as soon as they happen.

There are downsides with this approach too though. For example, you'll want to keep that array of activities trimmed down or you could be getting a large blob of data for a single user & then throwing away a load of it.